# Getting message list being processed in ProcessMessage()

Tags: windows, sendmessage

I am debugging a crash that occurs in the *ProcessMessage()* method. I have checked other parts from my code to try to find where could a message be sent that would cause this without success. So the option I'm left with is to try to see what are the messages that *ProcessMessage()* is processing.

Does anyone know if there is a way to get the message list that *ProcessMessage()* will iterate? Or, if it is not possible, how to capture every message sent using the *SendMessage()* function?

**EDIT** : 
*ProcessMessage()* and *SendMessage()* are not my code, *ProcessMessage()* is from a *TApplication* object and *SendMessage()* is a Windows function.

Comment: Why not log the message when you start processing it?

Comment: The ProcessMessage() method I mentioned is not my code, it's from TApplication object. I will edit the question to be clearer.

Comment: So it's Delphi? Can't you override the method and add the logging?

Comment: Actually it's Borland C++ class. 
Well, there are two problems to this approach that I wouldn't know how to resolve :

1. There seems to be a global Application instance of TApplication and I can't find where it is created. So, I don't now where I would create a subclass object instead of a straight TApplication object.

2. Even if problem 1 was solved, I would subclass the ProcessMessage() but how would I log the messages? I need to know how are stored the messages TApplication for that, and I haven't found anything in the documentation explaining that.

Comment: Are there other conditions related to the crash? E.g. when does it happen, how often, is the application taking a lot of memory...? Are you calling `ProcessMessages` yourself, or is it only used in the main message loop? Is the application multi-threaded? Are you perhaps calling `ProcessMessages` from a different thread?

Comment: Here are the answers to your questions :

- The application I'm working in is heavy : memory consuming and with a big code base involved, so memory usage can't be used to diagnose something. Save thing for "other conditions related to the crash", there are some but they don't seem to have anything to do with windows messages (I couldn't find any message being sent in the code involved with the crash).
- Yes, ProcessMessages() is being called manually. I know this is an ugly practice but I can't do anything about it at this stage.
- This is a single-threaded application

Comment: I now have the answer I needed... Thank you very much for taking your time to help me!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to debug the message list : logging into main form's WndProc() method. All messages being processed are processed here, so I can log them and debug the application from this point.